# How to make requests between Android and PHP only

Tags: php, android

So I've got an Android app witch makes several requests to my server with PHP (POST and GET) and I was wondering if there is a way to make the PHP code work only if the request came from my app and only my app (basically check where the request came from and verify it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is authentication.

There's a number of different ways you can go about it.

You could use OAuth2:

https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate

https://oauth.net/code/php/

Or at a very basic level you can create a token and include it in the header of your client (Apps) requests and verify it on the server (PHP) side.
It's not very secure but if you're looking for something basic to start with that'll do.

Comment: Yes but what if my app can be used without a login?

Comment: You still need to authenticate the app itself.
There's one set of authentication for your users and one set for your app.

Comment: @Carlosat Then no.  Mathematically there's no way to do that.  Any code or other secret you use to identify your app would need to be in the client, and with that it could be reverse engineered.  You can securely authenticate a user because there's a shared secret between your server and the user that a bad actor can't (easily) detect.  There's no way to do that with your app, as its running on uncontrolled hardware and can be reverse engineered.